# ActiveSupport::TestCase vs Test::Unit::TestCase when unit testing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda, factory-bot

I recently noticed my test database is not being cleaned up after my tests run if my tests subclass Test::Unit::TestCase. If my tests subclass ActiveSupport::TestCase, everything is cleaned up properly.

Can anyone explain why, and/or provide an explanation of using one versus the other?

I am using shoulda and factory_girl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you [take a look at the code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/test_case.rb), you'll see `ActiveSupport::TestCase` has a lot of of setup and utility functions for testing Rails. Older versions of Rails used to use `Test::Unit::TestCase` with a lot of mixins, but moved to subclassing a while ago.

If you're testing a Rails app, you should subclass `ActiveSupport::TestCase` or `ActionController:TestCase` for controllers. The generators will do this automatically, so you should not have to think about it most of the time.